# detect when 'comma' is pressed in GLUT

Tags: opengl, glut

I have "glutKeyboardFunc (keyboard);" in my main function, How I can detect when user press 'comma' or full-stop. I want to move (strafe) to your left in the XZ plane a distance when comma is pressed. and move to right in the XZ plane when full-stop is pressed. The current code does not response.

```
 if(key==GLUT_KEY_UP)
{
  eyez = eyez + RUN_SPEED;
}
else if(key==GLUT_KEY_DOWN)
{
  eyez = eyez - RUN_SPEED;
}
else if(key==',')
{
  eyex = eyex - RUN_SPEED;
}
else if(key=='.')
{
  eyex = eyex - RUN_SPEED;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`glutKeyboardFunc()`](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node49.html) callback is only for ASCII-type keys.  I'm surprised you are getting arrow key events from it.

Create a [`glutSpecialFunc()`](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node54.html) callback for non-ASCII keys.

Answer (score 1):

What you need here, dear fellow UoM student enrolled in COMP27112, is the ASCII codes for comma and dot.

That is 44 and 46 respectively.

```
case 44:
  // Comma
  break;
case 46:
  // Dot
  break;
```